# Global variable in android fragment class not working

Tags: android, variables, android-fragments, global

I have some problems with my android app. I use a fragement to show two date pickers and a button which calls a method in the activity and then the method calls a getter for the datepicker value.
The problem is, that the method which is the getter always returns null for the selected date picker item. The date picker object is called by findViewById in the  onCreateView method and is set as a class variable. There, the object could be find and in this method it is possible to get the selected value.
But when I try to use the value within the getter method which is called from outside the class variable for the date picker is always set to null. I don't understand the problem and after searching for nearly two days I hope you can help me.

Here is the the fragment xml Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabelStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_startDate" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePickerStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabelEndDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_endDate" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePickerEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:onClick="calculateSelectedAverageData"
        android:text="@string/button_calculate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the method in the activity (called when pressing the button):

```
public void calculateSelectedAverageData(View view) {
    FitnessDateFragment dateFragment = (FitnessDateFragment) mPagerAdapter
            .getItem(1);
    System.out.println(dateFragment.getStartDate());
    System.out.println(dateFragment.getEndDate());
    Toast.makeText(this, "New data for selected time created",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is my fragment (onViewCreated datePicker values aren't null but in the getter methods):

```
public class FitnessDateFragment extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayout fragmentLayout;

    DatePicker datePickerStart;
    DatePicker datePickerEnd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_fitness_date_fragment, container, false);
        datePickerStart = (DatePicker) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.datePickerStart);
        datePickerEnd = (DatePicker) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.datePickerEnd);
        return fragmentLayout;
    }

    public long getStartDate() {
        Calendar calendarStart = new GregorianCalendar(
                datePickerStart.getYear(), datePickerStart.getMonth(),
                datePickerStart.getDayOfMonth());
        return calendarStart.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    public long getEndDate() {
        Calendar calendarEnd = new GregorianCalendar(datePickerEnd.getYear(),
                datePickerEnd.getMonth(), datePickerEnd.getDayOfMonth());
        return calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Log with Exception:

```
01-22 20:00:29.485: W/dalvikvm(24195): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d78a08)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3626)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3621)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    ... 11 more
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at com.uni.fitnesstracker.FitnessDateFragment.getStartDate(FitnessDateFragment.java:36)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    at com.uni.fitnesstracker.FitnessGUI.calculateSelectedAverageData(FitnessGUI.java:101)
01-22 20:00:29.490: E/AndroidRuntime(24195):    ... 14 more
```

EDIT FitnessGUI:

I skipped the point, that I'm using a ViewPager to swipe between three Fragments:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fitness_recorder);


mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

// Service Connection
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FitnessService.class);
bindService(intent, connectedService, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
isBound = true;

// Elements for data
averageDataForPieChart = new FitnessDataAverage[3];
```

}

The main xml is the following:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The PagerAdapter:

```
package com.uni.fitnesstracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment result;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            result = new FitnessRecorderFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            result = new FitnessDateFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            result = new FitnessResultFragment();
            break;
        default:
            result = new FitnessRecorderFragment();
            break;
        }
        result.setArguments(args);
        return result;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String result;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            result = "Recorder";
            break;
        case 1:
            result = "Date";
            break;
        case 2:
            result = "Result";
            break;
        default:
            result = "Recorder";
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know they are not null and are you sure there is no excpetion in logcat?

Comment: should it not be `datePickerStart = (DatePicker) fragmentLayout.findViewById(
                R.id.datePickerStart);`

Comment: The code with fragmentLayout.findViewById also doesn't work. I put a syso method with parameter datePickerStart and in onCreateView it prints a value for the variable and in getDateStart it returns null

Comment: what is line 36 `FitnessDateFragment.java`?

Comment: datePickerStart.getYear(), datePickerStart.getMonth(), sourrounded by method getStartDate

Comment: datePickerStart is null

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a date that is "static" and not changing to populate your pickers than why dont you just pass it to your fragment via arguments in a bundle and get them in your fragments onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Your `datePickerStart` and `datePickerEnd` both are null. You need to check whether fragment is attached before calling those methods.

Also instead of using `System.out.println` use `Log.i`

Example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FitnessDateFragment fragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new FitnessDateFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    public void calculateSelectedAverageData(View view) {
        if(fragment.isAdded())
        Log.i("Start date is",""+fragment.getStartDate());
        Log.i("End date is",""+fragment.getEndDate());
        Toast.makeText(this, "New data for selected time created",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabelStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label_startDate" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePickerStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabelEndDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label_endDate" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePickerEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:onClick="calculateSelectedAverageData"
        android:text="button_calculate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FitnessFragment

```
public class FitnessDateFragment extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayout fragmentLayout;

    DatePicker datePickerStart;
    DatePicker datePickerEnd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.frag, container, false);
        datePickerStart = (DatePicker) fragmentLayout.findViewById(
                R.id.datePickerStart);
        datePickerEnd = (DatePicker) fragmentLayout.findViewById(
                R.id.datePickerEnd);
        return fragmentLayout;
    }

    public long getStartDate() {
        Calendar calendarStart = new GregorianCalendar(
                datePickerStart.getYear(), datePickerStart.getMonth(),
                datePickerStart.getDayOfMonth());
        return calendarStart.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    public long getEndDate() {
        Calendar calendarEnd = new GregorianCalendar(datePickerEnd.getYear(),
                datePickerEnd.getMonth(), datePickerEnd.getDayOfMonth());
        return calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a skipped part of the main activity because I'm using a ViewPager to swipe between the Fragments

Comment: @Roman view pager should not be a problem also. the method is the same

Comment: But when I try to use method getFragmentManager() eclipse says that it's not avaiable. Is there a problem in the PagerAdapter that I always return a new Fragment when calling the method getItem()?

Comment: @Roman it will work if you do it right. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html